# Matplotlib/Seaborn box plot with lots of information

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to plot the results of experiments with 3 different datasets with 11 models over 4 metrics, each with 100 datapoints. I understand that getting all this information into one plot is very difficult to do and probably even more difficult to read. Currently, I have 12 plots, one for each experiment/metric (3*4) and the results of all 11 models in one plot. I am trying to reduce this 4 plots: one for each metric with the 11 models and 3 experiments in the same plot.

More specifically, the metrics I working with are sensitivity, specificity, PPV, and AUC. There are 3 different experiments: *notes_common*, *full_common_vital*, *full_common_all*. And I have 11 models. Currently, this is the code that I have to get the data ready for plotting:

```
prefix = 'notes_common_vital'

bams = pickle.load(open(workdir/f'{prefix}_bams.pkl', 'rb'))
for k in bams.keys():
  bams[k.upper()] = bams.pop(k)
bams['AVG-ALL'] = bams.pop('AVG-LR-RF-GBM')
bams['MAX-ALL'] = bams.pop('MAX-LR-RF-GBM')

itr = iter(bams.keys())
bams.keys()

metrics = {}

for md in itr:
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  for k, m in bams[md].yield_metrics():
    df[k] = m
  df['model'] = md
  cols = list(df.columns)
  cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
  df = df[cols]
  metrics[md] = df

plot_df = pd.concat(metrics.values())
```

`bams` is just an object of a custom class that I created to hold binary average metrics over 100 iterations.

```
plot_df.shape
(1100, 5)

plot_df.columns
Index(['model', 'Sensitivity', 'Specificity', 'PPV', 'AUC'], dtype='object')

plot_df.head()

    model   Sensitivity Specificity PPV AUC
0   LR  0.782575    0.607646    0.389910    0.763138
1   LR  0.810860    0.537603    0.362753    0.752767
2   LR  0.823888    0.598635    0.341402    0.784208
3   LR  0.810928    0.617947    0.356734    0.782843
4   LR  0.833948    0.553218    0.333702    0.765500
```

For plotting:

```
met = 'Sensitivity'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,8))
sns.boxplot(x='model', y=met, data=plot_df, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('')
```

which results in
[image]

Now I do this for each experiment by changing the `prefix` and each metric by changing `met` to result in 12 plots like this. This is way too many number of plots for me to present in a presentation, so I need a way to more succinctly present these results.

I was thinking, whether, I could have one plot per metric and have all the models for each experiment in the X-axis (but with width really small) with wide image, such that there would be 33 models in a given figure, so that I could show the comparison more easily. I'm not sure how to do this. I welcome other suggestions on how to present these results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine (concatenate) each of your three datasets into a single data frame with an identifier variable column for each dataset.  Then you can plot it exactly as your are, but include the `hue=` argument to separate the datasets.  Here's an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('01-01-2000', '12-31-2002')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(dates), 11)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))
df.index = dates
df = df.reset_index().melt(value_vars=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'), id_vars='index').set_index('index')
df['dataset'] = df.index.year
df

>     index    variable value   dataset         
>     2000-01-01    A   47  2000
>     2000-01-02    A   89  2000
>     2000-01-03    A   79  2000
>     2000-01-04    A   24  2000
>     2000-01-05    A   87  2000
>     ...   ... ... ...
>     2002-12-27    K   62  2002
>     2002-12-28    K   67  2002
>     2002-12-29    K   46  2002
>     2002-12-30    K   62  2002
>     2002-12-31    K   73  2002
>     12056 rows × 3 columns

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
sns.boxplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value', hue = 'dataset', data = df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works great. However, the plot is a bit noisy and finding the separation is a bit difficult. Is it possible to maybe draw a line between A,B,C..?

Comment: You could do `for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):plt.axvline(x=i+0.5)`. But the more you add to the plot, the more noisy it will be.